# Creating xml with dynamic tag through xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

This is how my xml looks like:

```
<pkt>
    <row name="ARENDEN" actn="M">
        <col name="ARNR" type="num" val="82844316"/>
        <col name="KUNDNR" type="num" val="290125"/>
    </row>
</pkt>
```

I have written an XSLT stylehseet which transforms it to

```
<col>ARNR</col>
<col>KUNDNR</col>
```

But `ARNR` should come in place of tag, basicaly tags should be defined dynamically with the column names and `val` will be the value from source-example.

```
<ARNR>82844316</ARNR>
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example XML input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <pkt>
    <row name="ARENDEN" actn="M">
      <col name="ARNR" type="num" val="82844316"/>
      <col name="KUNDNR" type="num" val="290125"/>
    </row>
  </pkt>
  <pkt>
    <row name="HEINZ" actn="M">
      <col name="HNZ" type="num" val="465798"/>
      <col name="PRODNR" type="num" val="321654"/>
    </row>
  </pkt>
</root>
```

XSLT stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="root/pkt/row"/>
    </output>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row">
    <entry>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="col"/>
    </entry>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="col">
    <xsl:element name="{@name}">
      <xsl:value-of select="@val"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<output>
  <entry>
    <ARNR>82844316</ARNR>
    <KUNDNR>290125</KUNDNR>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <HNZ>465798</HNZ>
    <PRODNR>321654</PRODNR>
  </entry>
</output>
```

Comment: Hello,The code is working just fine but only for one occurrence.in the same xml i have multiple occurance of `<pkt>
    <row name="ARENDEN" actn="M">
        <col name="ARNR" type="num" val="82844316"/>
        <col name="KUNDNR" type="num" val="290125"/>
    </row>
</pkt>` where the rowname and col name are changing. any help?

Comment: You need to adapt the XPath for `apply-templates` in the root template of course. Changed my example a bit to show how.